# How to make a column that determine quadrant given 'X' and 'Y' coordinate columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, apply

#Excuse me, i want to ask you something, give that:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,0.4,-0.5,2,-0.8,3,4],'Y':[2,-1,-0.2,3,1,-0.9,1]})
print(data)
```

#Then, i want to make a new column, call it 'Z' that determine the quadrant (X,Y) given column 'X' and 'Y'. First i make the function like this

```
def Quadrant(x,y):
    if x>=0 and y>=0:
        print('Quadrant 1')
    elif x<0 and y>=0:
        print('Quadrant 2')
    elif x<0 and y<0:
        print('Quadrant 3')
    else:
        print('Quadrant 4')
```

#When i ran this script to apply that function in new column (in IDLE Python 3.8)

```
data['Z'] = data[['X','Y']].apply(lambda x: Quadrant(x['X'],x['Y']),axis=1)
```

#It make output like this:

```
Quadrant 1
Quadrant 4
Quadrant 3
Quadrant 1
Quadrant 2
Quadrant 4
Quadrant 1
```

And when i check the new column
'Z' with print(data),
it gave me output:

```
    X    Y    Z
0  1.0  2.0 None
1  0.4 -1.0 None
2 -0.5 -0.2 None
3  2.0  3.0 None
4 -0.8  1.0 None
5  3.0 -0.9 None
6  4.0  1.0 None
```

#Same with i ran this script

```
data['Z'] = data.apply(lambda x: print('Quadrant 1') if x[0]>=0 and x[1]>=0 else ( print('Quadrant 2') if x[0]<0 and x[1]>=0 else ( print('Quadrant 3') if x[0]<0 and x[1]<0 else print('Quadrant 4'))),axis=1)
```

#It gave output like this

```
Quadrant 1
Quadrant 4
Quadrant 3
Quadrant 1
Quadrant 2
Quadrant 4
Quadrant 1
```

How to make new columns with output like this?

```
    X    Y      Z  
0  1.0  2.0 Quadrant 1
1  0.4 -1.0 Quadrant 4
2 -0.5 -0.2 Quadrant 3
3  2.0  3.0 Quadrant 1
4 -0.8  1.0 Quadrant 2
5  3.0 -0.9 Quadrant 4
6  4.0  1.0 Quadrant 1
```

Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Replace `print` with `return`. `apply` will use the `return` from the lambda function.

Comment: Please change the title to something that actually describes the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and the result shows that you wrongly used the "print()" function.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 0.4, -0.5, 2, -0.8, 3, 4], 'Y': [2, -1, -0.2, 3, 1, -0.9, 1]})
print(data)


def Quadrant(x, y):
    if x >= 0 and y >= 0:
        return 'Quadrant 1'
    elif x < 0 and y >= 0:
        return 'Quadrant 2'
    elif x < 0 and y < 0:
        return 'Quadrant 3'
    else:
        return 'Quadrant 4'


data['Z'] = data[['X', 'Y']].apply(lambda x: Quadrant(x['X'], x['Y']), axis=1)
print(data)
```

You should replace "print" with "return" in your specific function.